# Why there is no application.properties in my Spring Boot apllication?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I made a package using Spring Boot Initalizer website with the following:

- Kotlin
- Gradle Kotlin
- 3.0.2

But I don't have the application properties file in my project. Where can I set the required properties ? Also, there is any documentation available with all of them ?

- I tried searching on Google. But mostly are older versions of Spring Boot so that is not relevant
- I tried searching on official website but nothing describes what I search.

Answer (score 2):

Generated the spring boot app with same configuration using Spring Initializr.
The 'application.properties' file is present in src > main > resources folder.

[Spring Initializr - Kotlin, Gradle](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project-kotlin&language=kotlin&platformVersion=3.0.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo)